# Remove the new item button from views

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer

I have a template that has custom views and permissions. The template consists of 1 list that has a custom permission that means they can only EDIT items in the list (No DELETE and no ADD).
The main view of the list uses grouping and then makes use of the edit icon that appears next to each item. The issue I have is that regular users who only have edit permission cannot see this edit icon! They can only see this icon when I grant them ADD permission but then this allows them to see the Add new item button. So how do I remove this button or fix the permission behaviour surrounding the EDIT icon in the view?

Comment: Can't you use the column "Edit (link to edit item) " in your list view?

Comment: I have done thanks, but this only serves as a work around. As I do not want to grant them add I will have to settle for this